# How can I install node.js without putting it in the path?

Tags: linux, node.js, macos, path, installation

I have an older node.js installed on my mac, that is still needed, but for some other application a newer version is needed as well that I would like to access using full path, so that the node command uses the older version.

So is there a way to compile from source or install node.js without modifying the PATH?

PS.: newer npm is needed for the newer node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [nvm (node version manager)](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) package is designed to allow you using multiple node versions without modifying the system PATH.
You even can specify the required node version per project directory.

Comment: This way the npm stays as is, but I need that as well with the newer node.js

Comment: npm is installed together with the selected node version and is available on the path when the version is used.